# How to refresh dynamic contents in Wicket when you press F5?

Tags: java, apache, refresh, wicket

I've implemented a MatchPage which displays the following informations:

- MatchStatus (OPEN/CLOSED)
- Winner (Name of the Winner)
- Form to upload files

(follow the link to see how it looks like, [1]: http://www10.pic-upload.de/25.04.13/klmy9fe8cgk3.png)

Now here comes the problem. Let's assume, someone is reporting a result while another one has currently open the specific MatchPage. When the report is done, the MatchStatus will change from OPEN to CLOSED, the color will change from OPEN=green to CLOSED=red, the Winner will be set and the Form for uploading files will disappear (see [2]: http://www7.pic-upload.de/25.04.13/9diu5bcbws9.png).

The player who reported the result will see the updated MatchPage while the other one will still see the old version of the MatchPage, even if he refreshed the browser.

I could solve the problem with OPEN/CLOSED by using my own LoadableDetachableModel:

```
@Override
public String load()
{
    Match m = dao.getMatchFromID(match_id);
    String result = "OPEN";

    if (m.getClosed())
    {
        result = "CLOSED";
        reportForm.setVisible(false); //does not work
        colorBehavior.setColor("red"); //does not work

    }

    return result;
}
```

Label on my MatchPage:

```
matchStatus = new Label("matchStatus", new MyMatchModel(m.getMatch_id(), matchDAO, reportForm));
```

As you can see on the load() method, setting the reportForm invisible and setting the color to red does not work.

Any idea how i can solve such kind of problem? How can i make the form disappear and change the color to red when the user pressed F5/refresh the browser.

Comment: After setting the visibility are you re-rendering the page? Also i would not bet on that that the user knows he has to press F5 or Refresh. If it is essential i would use an `AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the "isVisible()" method of the form like this:

```
public boolean isVisible() {
  return !yourModel.getObject().getClosed();
}
```

Comment: or better override `onConfigure` and there `setVisible(yourModel.getObject().getClosed())` as `isVisible()` is called multiple times during rendering and `onConfigure()` only once. As he is reaching to the DB this might improve performance.

Comment: Yes, +1. Though, in the same request, the model will not load more than once (it won't be serialized until after the page rendering).

Comment: Well, thank you guys. It worked for the form but what about changing the color via the ColorBehavior? Same procedure?

Comment: Ok solved it with creating my own label and overriding onConfigure()